# PHP `json_encode` incorrectly turn array into `{}`

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

My system is centos 7.4 with PHP 5.4

```
$s='a:91:{s:13:"spotsviewvars";s:7:"1916.74";s:13:"100000T18vars";N;s:17:"100000T18S106vars";s:7:"1746.95";s:17:"100000T18S107vars";s:4:"4.49";s:17:"100000T18S108vars";s:4:"8.29";s:17:"100000T18S109vars";s:4:"4.38";s:17:"100000T18S110vars";s:3:"5.4";s:17:"100000T18S111vars";s:4:"3.88";s:17:"100000T18S112vars";s:4:"3.49";s:17:"100000T18S113vars";s:4:"5.55";s:17:"100000T18S114vars";s:4:"3.58";s:17:"100000T18S115vars";s:3:"5.5";s:17:"100000T18S116vars";s:5:"10.39";s:17:"100000T18S117vars";s:4:"6.52";s:17:"100000T18S118vars";s:4:"6.09";s:17:"100000T18S119vars";s:3:"6.7";s:17:"100000T18S120vars";s:4:"4.18";s:17:"100000T18S121vars";s:5:"14.81";s:17:"100000T18S122vars";s:3:"3.9";s:17:"100000T18S123vars";s:4:"4.93";s:17:"100000T18S124vars";s:4:"4.06";s:17:"100000T18S125vars";s:4:"5.03";s:17:"100000T18S126vars";s:4:"5.73";s:17:"100000T18S127vars";s:4:"3.13";s:17:"100000T18S128vars";s:3:"7.2";s:17:"100000T18S129vars";s:4:"7.03";s:17:"100000T18S130vars";s:4:"3.81";s:17:"100000T18S131vars";s:3:"7.4";s:17:"100000T18S132vars";s:4:"7.82";s:17:"100000T18S133vars";s:4:"3.96";s:13:"100000T19vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S134vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S135vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S136vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S137vars";s:5:"12.54";s:17:"100000T19S138vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S139vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S140vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S141vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S142vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S143vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S144vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S145vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S146vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S147vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S148vars";N;s:17:"100000T19S149vars";N;s:13:"100000T18S106";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S107";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S108";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S109";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S110";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S111";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S112";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S113";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S114";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S115";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S116";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S117";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S118";s:2:"A1";s:13:"100000T18S119";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S120";s:2:"A1";s:13:"100000T18S121";s:2:"A1";s:13:"100000T18S122";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S123";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S124";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S125";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S126";s:2:"A1";s:13:"100000T18S127";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S128";s:2:"A1";s:13:"100000T18S129";s:2:"A1";s:13:"100000T18S130";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S131";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T18S132";s:2:"A1";s:13:"100000T18S133";s:2:"A2";s:13:"100000T19S134";N;s:13:"100000T19S135";N;s:13:"100000T19S136";N;s:13:"100000T19S137";s:0:"";s:13:"100000T19S138";N;s:13:"100000T19S139";N;s:13:"100000T19S140";N;s:13:"100000T19S141";N;s:13:"100000T19S142";N;s:13:"100000T19S143";N;s:13:"100000T19S144";N;s:13:"100000T19S145";N;s:13:"100000T19S146";N;s:13:"100000T19S147";N;s:13:"100000T19S148";N;s:13:"100000T19S149";N;}';
$s_array=unserialize($s);
var_dump($s_array);
$s_json=json_encode($s_array,JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
var_dump($s_json);
```

You will notice strange result when run above PHP script.

`$s_array` is `array`,`json_encode` result should be something like `[]`,but result is `{}`.
What's the problem?

Comment: Type dumping the type of s_array after the call to unserialize.

Comment: @SPlatten var_dump() already shows the type at the start of the output. it says "array". gettype() will say the same. Which doesn't really enlighten the OP in the context of this question.

Comment: As has already been said, PHP has associative arrays, JavaScript doesn't.

Comment: @SPlatten that is certainly true, but the question is about JSON, not JavaScript. The same statement is true of both, but we have no idea whether this data is going to be used in a JavaScript context or not. JSON data and JavaScript objects are not the same thing and there _are_ some differences here and there. (P.S. Apologies if that's teaching you to suck eggs and in fact JSON/JavaScript was just a slip of the keyboard on your part on this occasion, but I thought I would point it out for anyone else reading, as much as anything).

Comment: @ADyson, Javascript is the same as JSON in terms of arrays and objects you cannot have an associative array in JSON, arrays are indexed automatically numerically from 0 to N.

Comment: @SPlatten I know, I made the same point in my last comment. But nonetheless it's not technically correct to talk about JavaScript here. The data being produced is a JSON string, not a JavaScript object or array. It was a comment about terminology, not functionality

Comment: @ADyson, JSON is a Javascript born technology, thats the J in JSON, https://www.json.org/

Comment: @SPlatten born in it, but not the same thing as it. JSON is a textual data interchange format, it can be used anywhere, JavaScript is not required in order to use it. So making a comment saying what you can do in JavaScript is technically not relevant to a discussion about JSON. It so happens that in this case the same concepts apply, but that's merely an accident of history. No doubt you'll accuse me of pedantry or somesuch and I freely admit to it, if that also implies accuracy. Incorrect usage of terminology causes no end of problems and misunderstandings on this site, and in IT in general.

Comment: @ADyson, the point is that syntax is the same, you cannot do anything in JSON that isn't valid syntax in JavaScript.

Comment: @SPlatten I know, you're not telling me anything I don't know in that respect. You're missing my point. But I think I've made the point, there's no reason to continue a cross-purposes back and forth. Enjoy your day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to just have been confused by differences in terminology.

In PHP an "array" can either be an indexed array (in which you have a sequence of values) or an associative array (in which you have `name => value` pairs).

In JSON a sequence of values is stored in an array, and a set of `name => value` pairs is stored in an object.

Since you have `name => value` pairs in your data, you get an object when converting it to JSON.

For comparison:

```
$indexed_array = [ "foo", "bar", "baz" ];
$associative_array = [ "foo" => "A", "bar" => "B", "baz" => "C" ];
print json_encode($indexed_array);
print "\n";
print json_encode($associative_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working exactly as it should.

What you've got there is an *associative* array - i.e. each entry has a name (like `"spotsviewvars"`, or `"100000T18vars"` rather than a numeric index (like `0` or `1`). It's effectively a set of key/value pairs.

So in order to preserve that information when encoding as JSON, it has to be turned into an object instead - JSON has no concept of associative arrays. The only possible JSON representation which keeps both the key (e.g. `"spotsviewvars"`) and the associated value (e.g. `"1916.74"`) is an object.

If you turned it into a plain array you'd lose the key information, which I would assume is important. Every value would just have a numeric index to hold it instead, and you wouldn't know what its original meaning was.